# Using ACF Checkbox Field in a custom post type to filter the results of a different custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a single page that is looping through (custom post type 1). Nested inside of (custom post type 1) I have another loop for (custom post type 2). The goal is to have ACF Checkbox checkable in (custom post type 1) that filters the results for (custom post type 2) based on what is checked in (custom post type 1).

I'm new to StackOverflow and Wordpress development. But I have it working the way I described above with one fall back. You have to have the checkboxes available in (custom post type 2) for the $meta_query to work. Totally makes sense why after reading the documentation and how I have this setup.

How would I go about making it so (custom post type 2) doesn't need checkboxes for the filtering to work based off (custom post type 1) checked checkboxes?

```
<?php
// Custom Post Type 1
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type_1',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$custom_post_type_1 = get_posts( $args1 );

foreach( $custom_post_type_1 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    // Do things

    // Get the selected options from custom post type 1 and throw them into an array                         
    $my_acf_checkbox = get_field('checkbox', $post->ID);
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach( $my_acf_checkbox as $item ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'checkbox',
        'value' => $item,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
    }

    // Custom Post Type 2 (Nested)
    $args2 = array(                                      
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type_2',                                         
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );                                   
    $custom_post_type_2 = get_posts( $args2 );

    foreach( $custom_post_type_2 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        // Do things                                     
        wp_reset_postdata();                                     
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;                             
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just curious as to why you are using a checkbox ACF field? What are the values returned? Post IDs, Slugs? I would usually use a Post Object field and return an ID so it's a bit more dynamic than hardcoding values into a checkbox field.

I've assumed that you are returning post_ids in your checkbox for the solution below.

I can see what you are trying to do using the meta_query but if you have ids you can simply use post__in in your $args2 for the second loop so instead of this:

```
$my_acf_checkbox = get_field('checkbox', $post->ID);
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach( $my_acf_checkbox as $item ){
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'checkbox',
        'value' => $item,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}
```

Just push your ids into an array on their own like so:

```
foreach( $my_acf_checkbox as $item ){
    $cpt2s[] = $item;
}
```

Then use your new array in the post__in $args2:

```
$args2 = array(                                      
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type_2',                                         
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $cpt2s
);
```

Let me know if this will work as a solution for you or if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Appreciate the help @Paul! Worked like a charm. The reason for using the checkboxes was a request from the UX designer. But after your mention of Post Object and me digging a bit more to learn about Post Objects, it was a way better route to use Post Object and return an ID. Thanks again!