# How to filter archive posts using advanced custom field checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to filter custom post types on my WordPress site (using BeTheme) based on a `Checkbox` field. I've managed to get the field of the posts and display the correct posts when the field is a `Select` field, but I've read that the code needs to be changed for check boxes because they use serialization? I'm relatively new to PHP's deeper parts, so I think I'm confusing some concepts.

This is my code in `includes/content-post.php`:

```php
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'meta_key' => 'region', 'meta_value' => 'toronto', ) );
        query_posts( $args );
```

and this is the code I use in my archive page template:

```php
$acf_checks = get_field('region');

$meta_query[] = array(
                  'key'     => 'region',
                  'value'   => serialize($acf_checks),
                  'compare' => 'LIKE',
                );

$args = (array (
                    'post_type' => 'indiRes',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                    'meta_query' => $meta_query
                    //'meta_key' => 'region',
                    //'meta_value' => 'toronto',
                    // 'orderby' => 'date', 
                    // 'order' => 'DESC'
                )
                        );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 


                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();           
                ?>
                <p>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </p>
                <p class="1">
                    <?php the_field('region', get_the_ID()); ?>
                </p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I've tried a few different variations of code by references pages like [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/wp_query-using-meta_query-for-an-acf-checkbox-field/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877502/using-acf-checkbox-field-in-a-custom-post-type-to-filter-the-results-of-a-differ) but I'm sorta getting lost in what needs to be referenced and how.

Comment: What does `$acf_checks` actually contain (do a `var_dump` to find out), and what is actually stored in the database under the `region` meta key?

Comment: @CBroe so when I used `echo var_dump($acf_checks)`, it doesn't actually display anything on my page.  Am I using it incorrectly?

As for the `region` key, it's an advanced custom field that just carries the region choices for each of the custom post types I have. I've refreshed and set the region for a few of the posts to make sure that they are active.

Comment: The echo is not necessary, var_dump itself already writes output. But it should not be able to get you absolutely nothing - even a completely undefined variable should get you NULL at least.